# Expectation in a multinomial distribution (Problem)

Tags: probability, problem-solving, multinomial-coefficients

Here is a problem that I was expected to solve using normal approximation but I misread it and completely solved the problem. Let me know if the approach is correct; it's too hard to compute binomial coefficients for a number of terms.

**The problem Statement**

A stock trader has 100 shares of a company and adopts a random strategy for buying/selling of shares based on the outcomes of a die roll at each trading session. The strategy is to roll a die and make a choice based on the outcome:

1. Outcome =1 , then Do Nothing
2. 2 or 4 , Buy one share
3. 3 or 5, Sell one share
4. 6 , Buy two shares

Calculate an approximate probability that after 18 independent trading sessions the trader will have more than 110 shares of the company.

**The Solution** 
This is the solution that I have attempted. The probabilities for the following events are

1. Event = N ,Do nothing. Probability 1/6
2. Event = BO, Buy One. Probability 2/6
3. Event = SO,Sell One. Probability 2/6
4. Event = BT, Buy Two. Probability 1/6

The solution would be coefficient of $x^{10}$ (110 shares -100 shares) in the expansion of the following multinomial

$$\Big(  \frac{1}{6} + \frac{2x}{6} + \frac{2}{6x} + \frac{x^{2}}{6} \Big)^{18}$$

$$= \frac{1}{6^{18}} \Big( 1 + 2x + \frac{2}{x} + x^{2}\Big)^{18}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6^{18}} \Big( 1 + x^{2} + 2\frac{(x^{2} +1)}{x}  \Big)^{18}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6^{18}}  \frac{1}{x^{18}} (1+x^{2})^{18} (x+2)^{18} $$

Coefficients of $x$ of this expansion are
$$\binom{18}{r} (x^{2})^{r} \binom{18}{k} x^{k} 2^{18-k}$$

We are interested in coefficients of $x^{m}$ where $m  \ge 10$. Hence we need to find integer pairs $(r,k)$ such that
$$2r + k -18 = 10$$
$$2r + k = 28$$
$$r = 14 - \frac{k}{2}$$

Since $max(k)=18$ and $max(r)=18$ , the acceptable range of values for $k$ are $0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18$ and $14 \ge r \ge 5 $. The solution is

$$ \frac{1}{6^{18}} \sum_{k,r} \binom{18}{r}  \binom{18}{k}  2^{18-k}$$

Comment: What's your question exactly? Checking whether your solution to the full problem is correct?

Comment: Is my approach to the problem correct?

Answer (score 0):

The normal approximation only requires us to calculate the mean and variance of the change in the number of shares for a single session, then use the Central Limit Theorem to obtain an approximate probability.  That is to say, let $X_i \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$ be the random number of shares traded in session $i$.  We have $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = 1/3, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = 11/9.$$  Therefore, under the normal approximation, $$S = 100 + \sum_{i=1}^{18} X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 106, \sigma^2 = 22),$$ and the rest is straightforward.  Since $S$ is integer, it may be a good idea to use continuity correction in this case.

Whether this is a **good** approximation is a question that would be answered by computing the exact probability.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, much simpler and elegant than I arrived at for Normal approximation. But before taking up normal approximation, I solved it using exact methods via multinomial expansion as stated in the question. I did not compute the numerical value of the result I have arrived (as stated in question). Just wondering if you could comment on the method of solution using multinomial expansion that I worked. Thanks

Comment: @KiranKuppa Please note that you've made an error in your calculation; the denominator should be $6^{18}$, not $36^{18}$.  Also, you want the sum of all coefficients of terms with degree **strictly greater than** $10$, since the requested probability is for the total to exceed $110$.  The remaining part of your calculation will also need revision.  The exact probability should be about $0.169813$.